# How to show axis lables in bold font in Flotr2 Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flotr2

Im using Flotr2 Charts.

Can anyone help me to show the axis lables in bold font.

Here is the image:
[image]

Here is the flotr2 charts link for reference:
http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index#!advanced-titles

Comment: I believe documentation/examples may have some information. I just found this reference: http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index#!advanced-titles

Comment: I gone through that document and tried all options. But not not finding suitable option for showing axis labels in Bold font

Answer (score 2):

For the given example (http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index#!advanced-titles) set

```
HtmlText : true
```

and

```
tickFormatter : function (n) { return '<strong>('+n+')</strong>'; }
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added  what you have said but not getting axisbels in bold font.

Comment: graph = Flotr.draw(
    document.getElementById('podContent_'+id),flotrData,{
     colors:selectedColors,
     HtmlText : true,
        xaxis : {
          min:0,
     labelsAngle: 45,
     max:xaxisTicks.length+1,
     ticks:xaxisTicks,
     title : getXaxisLabel(),
     axisLabelFontSizePixels : 16,
     axisLabelFontFamily : "verdana",
     tickFormatter : function (n) { return '(<b>'+n+'</b>)'; }
        }

Comment: Weird. When I paste your code into the example page then it works fine. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Can you pls post your fiddle.